# Sorting 2D arrays with qsort - correct typecasting

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, qsort

I am having a problem with using c++ qsort compare function to correctly lexicographically sort  2d array of ints. I have already read many similar questions here but with no success. When making the custom compare function, its arguments are in form of

```
int compar (const void* p1, const void* p2)
```

now, I know that it the arguments are pointers to my variables, that are each ponters to one row of my array. I would like to index and compare my array in the normal conventional way using something like the following.

```
if(p1[0] <= p2[0]) {...}
```

Because I know, that the format

```
p1[i]
```

is just a shortcut for pointer arithmetic, I guess when I am recieving an argument "pointer to pointer to int", I should typecast and use it this way:

```
if(*(int**)p1[0] <= *(int**)p2[0]) {...}
```

Compiler however gives me many these errors

```
main.cpp:8:20: error: ‘const void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
main.cpp:8:37: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic  [-Wpointer-arith]
```

My question is, how to correctly typecast this, so it would allow me to compare my rows. Also, I would like to understand, what am I doing wrong here to avoid making these pointer related mistakes in the future.

Comment: In C++ you may want to consider `std::sort` instead of `qsort`

Comment: But there is still need to use this kind of custom compare function, and because I need to sort my array in more ways - lexicographically acording to cols 231, 321, 123 and so, this isn' t making it easier, I still have to typecast, or not?

Comment: No, you don't. C++ has got **templates** to handle types gracefully at compile time. `std::sort` is a shining example

Comment: Do you actually have a 2-dimensional array, in which case the cast is very wrong even if you "correct" it, or a one-dimensional array of pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `operator[]` takes precedence over cast. `b[0]` is trying to be resolved first. So even if it's `b[0]` it complains you are doing pointer arithmetic on `void*` type. You need to cast 1st.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[10];
    a[0] = 1337;
    a[1] = 42;
    void* b;
    b = (void*)a;

    //  cout << (int*)b[0] << '\n'; // will break
    cout << ((int*)b)[0] << '\n';

    // dedicated c++ cast imposes more verbose syntax - i.e. you can't miss the ()
    cout << static_cast<int*>(b)[1] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

That being said I still would encourage to use c++ dedicated features for what you're doing =).

Comment: It seems, that this was the culprit, I added parenthesis and compiler gives no errors, thank you!

Comment: It explains your error, but I still think going c-style is not the way =). You're welcome anyways =)